# Spring Web Flow Support in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-webflow-2

How do I get support for Spring Web Flow. I created a project with the required Spring modules but if i try to create a flow the message "no flow configuration found, please check spring setup" is shown. How do I setup Spring correctly?

Another Problem I have is that most of the Spring Web Flow configuration files are in an external jar file. How can I import this configuration files?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today, I resolved it!

**Open Project Structure:** Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S

**Click on Modules:** delete existing module and create a new one

Answer (score -1):

Spring is only supported by the Premium version of intellij so if you want it you need to purchase a licence,

You need to point Intellij to the Config files.

I am not able to open up my intellij at the moment, I am writing this whilst on an Oracle Java SE Pro course.

Comment: How can I do that if the config files are contained in an external jar?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but this is rather a comment and it doesn't answer the question at all. 
I would consider removing it.

Comment: You want it removed a year after posting?

Comment: And does it change *anything*? :) I'm really sorry, but it still is not useful, at all. Because it does not answer the question. It could be a nice comment though

Comment: These days no one uses config files but in code config